# Python Turtle Crashes MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, crash, turtle-graphics

Yes, I know there are already questions with a similar title, but I couldn't find a solution.

My problem is that whenever I use turtle, it crashes the entire computer. A video is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Awi0Geu1nH-396JJ2HQe6E8AnMUDnxJm/view?usp=sharing). This works with any turtle command, not just the one shown. It also crashes when I use any interpreter, not just the terminal.

I am running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6, with python 3.7.

Thank you for any help you may have.

Comment: Could you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem.